# iOS launch screen for light and dark modes

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, firemonkey, ios-darkmode

I follow the instruction in [RSP-12931: Native resolution not supported on iPAD Pro](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12931) to create an iOS LaunchScreen for my Delphi app. Now, with iOS 13, the problem is that I need 2 variants of this launch screen, one for dark mode and another for light mode. How do I create a basic launch screen in XCode that shows a customized background color w/ logo image in dark/light modes?

Comment: You only need one screen. You use dynamic colours and ensure that any images have a dark appearance version and iOS will take of the rest for you.

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks how to ensure that any images have a dark appearance? same for the background color ?

Comment: @loki I am unable to do it, nothing, I do not make it work. Could someone please upload an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all done inside an Asset Catalog.

For the logo, open your asset catalog and select the image. Now, select the  `Appearances` drop down on the right, and select `Any, Light, Dark`.

The Asset Catalog will now let you add different images for `Any` (pre-iOS 13), `Light` and `Dark` for that particular image:

[image: Support dark mode in Asset Catalog images]

For the background color, you'll need to define a custom `Color set` inside your asset catalog.

Press the `+` button at the bottom of your list of assets, and select `New Color set`.

Select the Color set that appears in your assets and, again, adjust the `Appearances` dropdown to read `Any, Light, Dark`.

You can now provide different colors for each mode using the RGB sliders underneath the `Appearances` dropdown:

[image]

Now, inside your storyboard you'll be able to select your custom color, and it will adapt depending on the mode running on the device:

[image]

You can test this by flipping the `Interface Style` widget at the bottom of the Interface Builder window between light and dark mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After adding images in assets catalog with respect to appearance. If the changes are not reflected, uninstall the application and restart the device.